# Mostrar un registro de Mysql en un textbox

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, vb.net, vs2019

estoy haciendo un programa en C# en Visual Studio 2022 y tengo una duda de como mostrar un registro de Mysql en un textbox. He visto varias preguntas con este tema, pero el problema es que en todos muestran como hacerlo abriendo la conexión a MySQL en el mismo archivo, pero yo tengo la conexión de MySQL en una clase aparte, para de ahí llamar todo a los distintos formularios que añada. Aún estoy aprendiendo a programar y no tengo muy claro como mostrar el registro, porque lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el ultimo ID en el textbox y sumarle 1 para que muestre cual sería el ID de ese registro, ya que en la base de datos tengo el ID como auto incrementable. Cualquier ayuda serviría, gracias.